# What is the meaning of every column when executing psig command?

Tags: process, solaris, signals

I try to use `psig` command to track signal dispositions of a process on `Solaris`:

```
bash-3.2# psig 3109
3109:   bash
HUP     caught  termsig_sighandler      0       HUP,INT,ILL,TRAP,ABRT,EMT,FPE,BUS,SEGV,SYS,PIPE,ALRM,TERM,USR1,USR2,VTALRM,XCPU,XFSZ,LOST
INT     caught  0x80c0e88       0
QUIT    ignored
```

What are the exact meanings of every column? I try to find it in Oracle [psig](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/psig-1.html#scrolltoc) document, but can't find the detail meanings of every column.

Comment: @NanXiao - you should've have cross-posted it, you should've flagged this Q for migration to that site. Please delete this one and I can reopen the U&L one afterwards.

Comment: While current Solaris source isn't available, this output hasn't changed in many years, so you can reference the source code in the [final OpenSolaris snapshot](https://java.net/projects/solaris/sources/on-src/show) - specifically [psig.c](https://java.net/projects/solaris/sources/on-src/content/usr/src/cmd/ptools/psig/psig.c?rev=1914).

Comment: @slm: Very sorry for my behaviors, I have deleted it.

Comment: @NanXiao - no problem, you didn't know. I've flagged this for migration now.

Comment: @slm: OK, thanks! Hope this can help more people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **first** column mean the signal that is sent. Use `kill -l` for a list of all signal that are available on your system (see the oracle documentation for the meaning of the signals, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4743/processmanagerusing-62/index.html) the most important ones).

The **second** column indicates whether the signal is caught by a signal handler of the process or not. `caught` means that there is a signal handler assiciated to the signal. Note that some signals can't be caught by the process (SIGKILL, SIGSTOP). Others are `ignored`. That means the process didn't react to the signal.

The **third** column is the userspace address of the handler.

The **fourth** column: The `sa_flags`: Special flags to affect behavior of signal. See [the different flags](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html) and their meanings

The **fifth** column: A list of signals to be blocked when the handler is executed.