# How to check the signal handler in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, linux-kernel, c

I have read this discussion which discuss about how to check the signal actions of each process:
[How can I check what signals a process is listening to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85364/how-can-i-check-what-signals-a-process-is-listening-to)

However, I want to use C/C++, Python or other ways to get the userspace of the signal handler name of each process. Just like the psig in Solaris:
[What is the meaning of every column when executing psig command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163573/what-is-the-meaning-of-every-column-when-executing-psig-command)

Would it be possible to do that in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

The `signal` function returns a pointer to the existing handler, if any.  You can set a signal to a known value, get the existing handler's address and restore it.

Comment: I just want to know how to get the handler's name, such as termsig_sighandler in this discussion:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163573/what-is-the-meaning-of-every-column-when-executing-psig-command

Comment: Restoring the value may fail with `SIG_ERR`. That's not a pretty situation to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Using [sigaction](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) instead of `signal` makes it possible to request the current signal handler without setting another handler. You just need to pass `NULL` as the second argument:

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9527540/2962407) for a code example.